# Get position of one image in another image

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing, imagemagick, frontend

I have a screenshot of my browser that displays a website.
Now I want to find out where the website (viewport) is positioned (relative to the whole screenshot). As seen as a rectangle with a black border in this image:

[image: Image showing a sample screenshot with a viewport]

I have the possibility to add anything to the DOM of the website before starting the image processing.

I already tried to generate a QR-Code, added it to the top left and lower right of the viewport and then used *imagemagick* in order to determine the position of the QR-Code in the bigger image:

```imagemagick
compare -metric "rmse" -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold "0.1" -virtual-pixel "edge" "haystack.png" "needle.png" "results.png"
```

However, this takes a veeery long time. In fact, I quit after 40 minutes.

I used a QR-Code because by using a timestamp I can be quite sure that this piece of image won't be found anywhere else on the website.

Also, the size of the QR-Code in the screenshot was double the size of the original QR-Code but I guess this is due to my mac screen having 144dpi.

I am using *node.js* so I need either something that can be executed via command line (like *imagemagick*) so that I can just execute it from node or a direct node module.

I have the advantage that I can choose what image I want to search for in the bigger image. I guess the exact knowledge of what is to be found can be a useful information to speed up the process (but I don't know how to use this information yet).

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing, but I can say that the subimage search time is proportional to the 4th power of the dimensions, so halving the sides should result in 1/16th of the run-time - at the expense of some granularity in location of the subimage. You could also consider a cross-correlation to find the sub-image.

Comment: I just tested your method by downsizing the original images to 20% and using a similary-threshold of 0.15.

This led to a total processing time of about 1.5 seconds!! Awesome! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a few suggestions that you might consider for speeding up your search if you are finding subimage search too slow.

**1. Reduce the Image Size**

I conducted a little experiment to test searching for variously sized needles in variously sized haystacks, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a range of haystack sizes
for h in 200 400 800; do
   # And a range of needle sizes
   for n in 10 20 40; do
      # Create haystack to search in, containing two needles
      convert -size ${h}x${h}! gradient:red-black -fill white \
              -draw "rectangle 100,100 139,139"               \
              -draw "rectangle 150,150 189,189"               \
              haystack.png
      # Create a needle this size to search for
      convert -size ${n}x${n}! xc:white needle.png

      cp haystack.png haystack_${h}x${h}.png
      cp needle.png   needle${n}x${n}.png

      # Search, measuring the time
      start=$SECONDS
      compare -dissimilarity-threshold 1.0 -metric rmse -subimage-search haystack.png needle.png null: > /dev/null 2>&1
      end=$SECONDS
      ((elapsed=end-start))
      echo Haystack:${h}x${h}, needle:${n}x${n}, time:$elapsed
   done
done
```

And found how the sizes affect the search times, like this:

```
Haystack:200x200, needle:10x10, time:2
Haystack:200x200, needle:20x20, time:2
Haystack:200x200, needle:40x40, time:2
Haystack:400x400, needle:10x10, time:8
Haystack:400x400, needle:20x20, time:8
Haystack:400x400, needle:40x40, time:10
Haystack:800x800, needle:10x10, time:33
Haystack:800x800, needle:20x20, time:36
Haystack:800x800, needle:40x40, time:47
```

As you can see, the sizes of the images make a big difference.

Here are the three haystacks, of varying sizes, each containing 2 white "*needles*":

[image]

And here are the "*result*" images where ImageMagick thinks the "*needles*" are located:

[image]

**2. Stop As Soon As Possible**

If you add the parameter `-similarity-threshold` and set it to a sensible value, you can make the searching stop as soon as the first good match is found - like `grep -m 1`.

Setting it like this will make it stop at the first perfect match (zero difference in similarity):

```
-similarity-threshold 0.0
```

or setting it like this will make it stop at the first *"pretty good match"*

```
-similarity-threshold 0.05
```

and the default setting is `1.0` which never matches and thereby causes the search to continue over the entire image.

Now I know you want to find the top and the bottom of the viewport, which is ***two*** matches and it may seem that quickly finding only the first match is no use. But Confucius, he say *"rotate your image"* :-)

So, find your first (i.e. top) match, then rotate your image (and needle) by 180 degrees and search again, but this time you are searching from the bottom and can again stop at the first match. (Rotate your result too.)

**3. Use all those lovely cores your paid for - parallelize!**

You can split the image up into parts and search in parallel to take advantage of all those lovely Intel cores you paid so much for. You need to be a bit careful to overlap a little so that your needle doesn't straddle the boundary along which you cut, but all you need is to add on a sliver the width of your needle to the search regions... like this

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a range of haystack sizes
for h in 200 400 800; do
   # And a range of needle sizes
   for n in 10 20 40; do
      # Create haystack to search in, containing two needles
      convert -size ${h}x${h}! gradient:red-black -fill white \
              -draw "rectangle 100,100 139,139"               \
              -draw "rectangle 150,150 189,189"               \
              haystack.png
      # Create a needle this size to search for
      convert -size ${n}x${n}! xc:white needle.png

      cp haystack.png haystack_${h}x${h}.png
      cp needle.png   needle${n}x${n}.png

      # Search, measuring the time
      start=$SECONDS
      compare -dissimilarity-threshold 1.0 -metric rmse -subimage-search haystack.png needle.png null: > /dev/null 2>&1
      end=$SECONDS
      ((elapsed=end-start))
      echo Haystack:${h}x${h}, needle:${n}x${n}, time:$elapsed

      ((a=h/2))
      ((b=h/2))
      ((c=a+n))
      ((d=b+n))
      ((e=a-n))
      ((f=b-n))
      # Measure time for parallel search, including dividing up image      
      start=$SECONDS
      convert haystack.png -crop ${c}x${d}+0+0       +repage h1.png
      convert haystack.png -crop ${a}x${b}+${a}+0    +repage h2.png
      convert haystack.png -crop ${a}x${b}+0+${b}    +repage h3.png
      convert haystack.png -crop ${c}x${d}+${e}+${f} +repage h4.png
      for p in 1 2 3 4; do
         compare -dissimilarity-threshold 1.0 -metric rmse -subimage-search h${p}.png needle.png null: > /dev/null 2>&1 &
      done
      wait
      end=$SECONDS
      ((elapsed=end-start))
      echo Parallel Haystack:${h}x${h}, needle:${n}x${n}, time:$elapsed
   done
done
```

And you can see the parallel times are almost 4x speeded up versus the single threaded times:

```
Haystack:200x200, needle:10x10, time:2
Parallel Haystack:200x200, needle:10x10, time:0
Haystack:200x200, needle:20x20, time:2
Parallel Haystack:200x200, needle:20x20, time:1
Haystack:200x200, needle:40x40, time:2
Parallel Haystack:200x200, needle:40x40, time:1
Haystack:400x400, needle:10x10, time:8
Parallel Haystack:400x400, needle:10x10, time:2
Haystack:400x400, needle:20x20, time:8
Parallel Haystack:400x400, needle:20x20, time:3
Haystack:400x400, needle:40x40, time:10
Parallel Haystack:400x400, needle:40x40, time:4
Haystack:800x800, needle:10x10, time:33
Parallel Haystack:800x800, needle:10x10, time:10
Haystack:800x800, needle:20x20, time:36
Parallel Haystack:800x800, needle:20x20, time:11
Haystack:800x800, needle:40x40, time:47
Parallel Haystack:800x800, needle:40x40, time:14
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot for your effort. This is exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. The rotation of 180° is not even necessary as I can just use two different qr codes or in general two different objects. Also, I'm thinking of replacing the qr codes with two plain filled rectangles with different colors. This way a downsizing of the image has no negative effect on the recognition. So I will rather make a color coding than a pattern coding. I would give 3 upvotes if I could ;)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of assistance.